# CURL PHP can't resolve host

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, php, curl, libc6

I'm trying a php script that is doing requests with CURL.

But I get the error Couldn't resolve host 'example.com'

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
if($result === false)
{
    echo 'Error Curl : ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'OK';
}
```

So I started to search the problem, I tried to do requests from my server with ping, curl (CLI) and telnet (that use libc6  like curl apparently)
nslookup works fine too

Everything work fine.

So where is the problem ?

Thanks for the help

- **Debian** Wheezy
- **libc6** 2.19-18
- **PHP** 5.6.8-1  (with php-fpm)
- **nginx**

Comment: Try the suggestion mentioned here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206748 should be similar in debian

Comment: If your question would be closed as off-topic, I suggest to retry it http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Hello, I tried everything here but it does not work, And it's weird because even curl in command line works...
I have a Java server on it that is doing requests and I don't have any problem. It's just php5-curl...